# S→∃x.Q(x) ⊢ ∃x.(S→Q(x)): How to prove the validity of this sequent in predicate logic?

Tags: proof-writing, natural-deduction

How to prove the validity of this sequent in predicate logic? Partial proof:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This proof is nastier than it might look at first. Solution:

[image: Solution]